# defining ideal of an ellipse and a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, projective-schemes

I would like to find an ideal $I=(f,g)\subset k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ with $V(I)\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ having 6 points where $\deg f=2$  (which is the homogeneous defining polynomial of an ellipse) and $\deg g=3$ (which is a homogeneous curve intersecting f in 6 points) and $f,g$ is a regular sequence.

I am a beginner in Algebraic Geometry and I have the shape of $V(f)\cup V(g)$ but I do not know how to find the ideal $I$[image: an ellipse intersecting a curve in 6 points in P^2].

Later note: I need the ideal to be the intersection of the defining ideals of the six intersecting points. I mean if $_1,…,_6∈ℙ_2$
are the intersecting points of the above two curves then $=∩_{i=1}^6_{_}$
, where $_{_}=(__−__:≠0,=1,2,3)$
. Can one find such complete intersection ideal? Is there any general formula for that?

Comment: $\langle (\frac{x}{2})^2 + (\frac{y}{\frac14})^2 -1, y-x(x-1)(x+1)\rangle$ would do.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks a lot for your reply. Indeed, I need the ideal to be the intersection of the defining ideals of the six intersecting points. I mean if $P_1, \ldots, P_6\in \mathbb{P}^2$ are the intersecting points of the above two curves then $I=\cap_{i=1}^6 I_{P_i}$, where  $I_{P_i}=(a_jx_k-a_kx_j: a_j\neq 0, k=1,2,3)$. Can one find such complete intersection ideal? Is there any general formula for that?

Comment: [Three of the points](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+256*y%5E2-x-8*y-14%3D0%2C32*x*y%2B7*x%2B8*y%2B2%3D0%2C4*x%5E2%2Bx%2B8*y-2%3D0) in the example above (click on exact forms). Writing them in the form you want would just move the complexity to describing the coefficients. Leaving the defining ideal as is or just computing a grobner basis for it might be the better.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks for your reply. Based on your suggested equations, I could construct such shape having 3 points (the other 3 points are symmetric).